# Plotting a Pandas DataSeries.GroupBy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, pandas

I am new to python and pandas, and have the following `DataFrame`.

How can I plot the `DataFrame` where each `ModelID` is a separate plot, `saledate` is the x-axis and `MeanToDate` is the y-axis?

**Attempt**

```
data[40:76].groupby('ModelID').plot()
```

[image]

**DataFrame**

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can make the plots by looping over the groups from `groupby`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for title, group in df.groupby('ModelID'):
    group.plot(x='saleDate', y='MeanToDate', title=title)
```

See for more information on plotting with pandas dataframes:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html
and for looping over a groupby-object:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups

Comment: The plots will be displayed on independent figures even without the `plt.figure()` first.

Comment: another nice tutorial on using `groupby` is here: https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_apply_operations_to_groups.html

Answer (score 10):

Example with aggregation:

I wanted to do something like the following, if pandas had a colour aesthetic like ggplot:

```
aggregated = df.groupby(['model', 'training_examples']).aggregate(np.mean)
aggregated.plot(x='training_examples', y='accuracy', label='model')
```

(columns: model is a string, training_examples is an integer, accuracy is a decimal)

But that just produces a mess.

Thanks to joris's answer, I ended up with:

```
for index, group in df.groupby(['model']):
    group_agg = group.groupby(['training_examples']).aggregate(np.mean)
    group_agg.plot(y='accuracy', label=index)
```

I found that `title=` was just replacing the single title of the plot on each loop iteration, but `label=` does what you'd expect -- *after* running `plt.legend()`, of course.