# Changing axis ticks in seaborn stripplotwhere x-value is a time stamp.

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Fellow data nerds,

I want to plot data from a dataframe, using seaborn functionality and alter the x-axis ticks.

I read in the data as such

```
import pandas as pd

with open(f) as fi:
    df = pd.read_csv(fi, delimiter=';', parse_dates = ['date'])
df.date = df.date.apply(lambda x: x.date())#removing time, only date remains
```

dataframe has three columns that are of importance for this issue:
`df.date`, `df.sedimentation` and `df.label`

the `df.date` has format `yyyy-mm-dd`
and is date object is of type: `datetime.date`

the `df.sedimentation` is of type: `numpy.float64`

the `df.label` is of type: `str`

I plot the data as following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = figsize)

sns.set_style( "darkgrid")

ax.set_title(title)
ax = sns.stripplot(data = df, x = 'date', y = 'sedimentation', hue = 'label')    
ax.set_ylim([-90,100])

plt.legend(ncol = 3, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc="upper left")

plt.show()
```

This gives the following image:

[image: Seaborn Image 1]

However, the ticks on the x-axis only shows the values as given in the dataframe `df`. I want to have a continues x-axis showing all the months per year. With the data points of `df.sedimentation` showing at the correct points of the x-axis.

So I add the following:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

years = mdates.YearLocator()   # set yearly ticker 
months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # set monthly ticker 
yearsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('\n\n%Y') # set format for year 
monthsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b') # set format for month 

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years) 
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(monthsFmt)

datemin = dt.date(df.date.min().year, 1, 1)
datemax = dt.date(df.date.max().year + 1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(datemin, datemax)
```

But here is were some weird mojo happens that I do not understand, I get this image:

[image: Seaborn Image 2]

**I get a beautiful x-axis ticker, but my data is not showing...**

So I thought, maybe there are two different axes-objects. One here:

`fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = figsize)` and one here:

`ax = sns.stripplot(data = df, x = 'date', y = 'sedimentation', hue = 'label')`

So I thought I would add the axes object `ax` to this:

`ax = sns.stripplot(data = df, ax = ax, x = 'date', y = 'sedimentation', hue = 'label')`

But this did not work. I found a work around by not using `seaborn` at all, and just using `matplotlib`and ``` pandas``groupby ``` [functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376159/plotting-a-pandas-dataseries-groupby). But I want to use `seaborn`, since i am especially interested in the `hue` functionality.

My question is thus: **Why is the data not showing when I alter the xaxis ticks?and How can I get my data to show on the axes object with still having the ticks that I want?**

Comment: A stripplot is a categorical plot. Your dates are shown as categories (i.e. one date per integer number, the axis ranges from 0 to len(categories)). In order to have the real dates on the axis, don't use any categorical plot. Instead `plt.scatter` might be an option.

Comment: thank you Mr. Wilde, however, I would prefer to remain using the seaborn, since it has functionality that is easier for analysis later on. And besides, I just want to understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: My comment explain why it does not work. As a consequence you cannot use a categorical plot, even if you want.

Comment: well than, I don't understand your comment. You only state that I am showing categories and in order to have the real dates I should use `plt.scatter`. I am not becoming any wiser...

Comment: Your first category is "2016-01-29", which will be shown at position 0 on the axis. Your second category is "2016-05-18", which is shown at position 1 on the axis, and so on. Your axis ranges from 0 to number_of_categories-1.

Comment: If you add it as an answer and elaborate I can give the green check and close the issue.

Comment: btw it took me mega long to write this question...don't get me wrong, the answer is good, but mega disappointing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `stripplot` is a categorical plot. As [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html) says:

> Draw a scatterplot where one variable is categorical.

Your dates are hence shown as categories (i.e. one date per integer number, the axis ranges from `0` to `len(categories)-1`). Your first category is "2016-01-29", which will be shown at position 0 on the axis. Your second category is "2016-05-18", which is shown at position 1 on the axis, and so on.

In order to have the real dates on the axis, don't use any categorical plot. Instead `plt.scatter` might be an option.

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rd = lambda : datetime(2017,np.random.randint(1,13),np.random.randint(1,29))
cats = ["Category {}".format(i) for i  in list("ABCD")]
df = pd.DataFrame({"date" : [rd() for i in range(29)],
                   "y" : np.random.rand(29),
                   "category" : np.random.choice(cats,size=29)})

dates = [d.to_pydatetime() for d in df["date"]]
u, c = np.unique(df["category"], return_inverse=True)

sc = plt.scatter(dates, df["y"], c=plt.cm.tab10(c))

scmap = lambda i: plt.plot([],[], marker="o",ls="none", c=plt.cm.tab10(i))[0]
plt.legend(handles=[scmap(i) for i in range(len(u))], 
           labels=list(u))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Alternatively using seaborn, you can use a `FacetGrid` to map to a `plt.scatter` plot, such the `hue` argument can be used.

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

rd = lambda : datetime(2017,np.random.randint(1,13),np.random.randint(1,29))
cats = ["Category {}".format(i) for i  in list("ABCD")]
df = pd.DataFrame({"date" : pd.Series([rd() for i in range(29)], dtype=object),
                   "y" : np.random.rand(29),
                   "category" : np.random.choice(cats,size=29)})


g = sns.FacetGrid(df, hue="category", size=3, aspect=2)
g.map(plt.scatter, "date", "y").add_legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: excellent! Thank you for explaining the concept, and showing a possibility to still use seaborn.